# How can I stop/disable McAfee ads/popups in Lenovo (Recommended by LENOVO)

Tags: windows-10, anti-virus, lenovo-laptop, popups, adblock

I have recently bought a Lenovo laptop with Windows 10 which has been good so far. However, there is something really annoying with it which is a an ad that appears every time I turn on the laptop.

This ad has the following text on it:

> Set up your McAfee account, and unlock the benefits!
>
> Activate now to make the most of your FREE, 30-day McAfee LiveSafe
>   trial:
>
> Protect all your household devices
>
> Securely store, manage and access your website passwords
>
> Get free information and technical support
>
> [Enter your e-mail] Activate device protection
>
> Recommended by LENOVO

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hctR.png)

Any ideas about how to disable this ad/pop-up

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You have McAfee software installed.  It is a trial of that particular version of the program.  You can either purchase the program which will give you a license to the program or remove the program.  In either case the advertisement will be prevented.

Comment: Just uninstall it, lenovo suggests because they make money from the subscription so feel free to uninstall it. It doesn’t help anyway.

Comment: @Valay_17: Why do you say that McAfee LiveSafe “doesn’t help”?

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' : It servers no purpose as it couldn’t detect any threats(I torrent a lot and I know where I can find malicious things, so I tried one to check if it is helpful)inspite of the administrative access that it already has from the manufacturer and neither did the purchased one. Neither does it pop any alert when installing third party applications.

Answer (score -1):

There should have a free version installed by default in your PC. 
You might try to uninstall that. Or you may buy a paid subscription.